# Is a woman murdered every 20 minutes for dowry?

Tags: criminology, marriage

I stumbled upon this image in Google images:

[image: 1 woman is murdered for dowry every 20 minutes.]

The image links to [www.50millionmissing.info](http://www.50millionmissing.info), which has, indeed, [created that poster](https://genderbytes.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/1-woman-murdered-every-20-minutes-poster/). The site is dedicated to Indian women.

Wikipedia explains the concept of [Dowry Deaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowry_death), including suicide and murder of young brides.

Is the claim true?

Comment: I've incorporated many comments into the question, so it is no longer about whether the OP understood it, but whether the claim is true. I removed the obsolete comments, and also answer attempts.

Answer (score 2):

A study from thelancet.com [reported](http://www.thelancet.com/pdfs/journals/lancet/PIIS0140-6736(04)17625-3.pdf):

> In India about 20 000 murders are committed every
>   year, of which women constitute about 10%–15% of the
>   total, ie, **about 2000 to 2500 per year**. Homicidal
>   burning of married women constitutes a significant
>   proportion of dowry deaths. Although it is difficult to
>   determine accurate numbers throughout the country,
>   extrapolation from our data suggests that homicide
>   may account for 600–750 deaths per year. Others **([see
>   Jutla in recommended reading](http://journals.lww.com/burncareresearch/pages/articleviewer.aspx?year=2004&issue=03000&article=00005&type=abstract))** suggest the figure may
>   be much higher. A 2000 New York Times article quoted an
>   official figure of **6975 dowry deaths in 1998**. Because of
>   the nature of the crime, it is improbable, if not
>   impossible, to know its true incidence. The
>   circumstances, however, are commonly described.

Comment: So using the 6975 figure that's about 1 ever hour and a quarter.